# How radio button is deselected?

Tags: radio-button, windows-phone-7.1

```
bool isChecked = false;

private void Agency3_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  isChecked = (bool)(((RadioButton)sender).IsChecked);
}

private void Agency3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton currentButton = (RadioButton)sender;
    if ((bool)currentButton.IsChecked && !isChecked)
    {
        currentButton.IsChecked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        currentButton.IsChecked = true;
        isChecked = false;
    }
}
```

This code helps deselect the radio button when it is clicked at the time when it was already selected.

I got this from a post on StackOverflow but it was closed.

Are both functions Agency3_Click() and Agency3_Checked() not called when a radio button is clicked?

What order are they called in which makes this behavior of deselecting a radio button possible?

Comment: what's the question you copied from? You should always include links to stuff you reference

Comment: you can always try putting breakpoints to know the flow.